# sed won't expand my BASH variable in script

Tags: bash, sed, quoting, variable

I have this script, which will prompt for the relative or absolute path to the file and then swap whitespaces **' '** with **'\ '** which works in Linux console. Substitution is done using the first **sed** command. After substitution I **echo** the path just for check and it is correct.

Then comes the second **sed** command which has to deal with the file for which I wrote the absolute path. Well it won't work... It looks like In the second command **$drill_file** isn't expanding. The weirdest thing is that it expands just fine outside the script... WOOT!?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Give relative or absolute path to the \"drill.TXT\" file:"

read drill_file_temp
drill_file=$(echo $drill_file_temp | sed -r 's/\s/\\ /g')
echo $drill_file

sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]\(Y[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/' $drill_file

echo "Conversion finished."
```

Comment: have you try: sed 's/.....' "$drill_file_temp"

Comment: "it expands just fine outside the shell"??

Comment: @Hauke I meant script - I fixed the mistake. Romeo. No I haven't tried yet because usualy 'echo "$variable"' returns same as 'echo $variable'

Comment: @Romeo. If I only add " ", then I get an error saying: `sed: can't read /home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/programi/eagle/projects/ISKRA/SLON\ -\ razsiritvena\ ploscica/v2.0/gerber/drill.TXT: No such file or directory
` but If I execute sed manualy it works - I do it like this: `sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]\(Y[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/' /home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/programi/eagle/projects/ISKRA/SLON\ -\ razsiritvena\ ploscica/v2.0/gerber/drill.TXT`

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put quoting chars into a string. The problem is that quoting chars are not parsed after parameter expansion. In order to get the desired effect you would need

```
eval sed ... $drill_file
```

You can use `set -x` to see how the shell sees the command line:

```
> text=a\\\ \\\ \\\ b
> echo $text
a\ \ \ b
> set -x
> : $text
+ : 'a\' '\' '\' b
```

I.e. the shell does not see one argument but four.

As aleady said by the others: You must quote `$drill_file` / `$drill_file_temp`: `"$drill_file"`

Comment: Putting eval in front does not work

Comment: @71GA It doesn't work if you forget the additional quoting layer you need for the `sed` command part. You can easily check with my simple example code: `eval : $text`

Comment: OK thank you I had to use eval and " " on the original path and not the edited. I mean who should know that I am forbidden to edit the path - in Linux whitespaces should be written as "\ " afterall... Not intuitive at all...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do the first sed if you quote your variables:

```
read -p "Give relative or absolute path to the \"drill.TXT\" file: " drill_file
if [[ -f "$drill_file" ]]; then
    sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]\(Y[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/' "$drill_file"
    echo "Conversion finished."
else
    echo "no such file: '$drill_file'"
fi
```

Comment: It's even worse: It doesn't work that way...

Answer (score 0):

**kernel doesn't understand \ (backslash)**
If `drill_file` is 'file\ with\ space', sed is executed as
`sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]\(Y[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/' file\ with\ space`.
First the shell clones itself and calls one the of execl family of functions passing args with argv[0]=sed, argv[1]=s/(^X[[:digit:]]*)[[:digit:]](Y[[:digit:]]*)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/, argv[2]=file\ , argv[3]=with\ and argv[4]=space. execl replaces shell with sed. When sed starts running, it calls `open("file\ ",O_RDONLY)`and does the same for 'with\ ' and 'space'. Kernel passes the request to relevent fs. Fs returns ENOENT meaning no such entry in the fs. That's true because really there are no such files. sed receives the error and displays error message.

if the $drill_file was quoted, sed gets the file name as 'file\ with\ space' and fails to open this time too.

`eval sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]\(Y[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/' "$drill_file"`
here eval parses its args and builds commands and executes the built command. It's just redundant and convoluted, you break and fix.

\ (backslash) escaping is only applicable when shell is running.`sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]\(Y[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/'` "**$drill_file_temp**" would have simply succeeded.
This works too.

```
sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]\(Y[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/' \
"$(read -p "Give relative or absolute path to the \"drill.TXT\" file: " \
drill_file_temp;echo $drill_file_temp)"
```